# GuzzleHttp not found

Tags: php, wordpress, guzzle, guzzle6

I have an annoying problem: I want to use GuzzleHttp\Client in my WP extension, but everytime I get an error:

> "Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/classes/MyPlugin/Plugin.php
>   on line..."

I have already checked out manipulations with Composer and Autoloader, in my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
}
```

also I added into htdocs/index.php:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

but this didn't bring any changes. What did I do wrong? Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: have you reloaded your autoloader file?

Comment: Have you run `composer.phar`? composer.json is the configuration for composer not your web app. check to see if the files are actually there

Comment: Yeah, in every case I have reloaded it once again, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I fogot to say that I used Guzzle in a Cronjob! So I added

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

to the wp-cron.php file, because cron jobs don't involve index.php just at all.